# EOFError: end of file reached with ftp.connect

Tags: ruby, heroku, ftp

I've had a good search around and have found some similar issues to this, but nothing similar enough to make anything work.

**Setup**

I am using Heroku to run a Ruby (off-Rails) script that basically takes data from an API to populate an ecommerce front page (for a Rakuten shop in Japan), intersperses the code with banners and reviews and then puts the HTML files onto the ecommerce service's FTP server.

**Code**

Because I have been trying to troubleshoot this all day, I have hardcoded the script to make it easier to paste step-by-step into IRB. It looks like this:

```
require 'uri'
require 'net/ftp'

uri = URI.parse('ftp://username:password@ftp.rakuten.ne.jp:16910')

ftp = Net::FTP.new

ftp.debug_mode = true
ftp.passive = true

ftp.connect(uri.host, uri.port) # ERROR OCCURS HERE
ftp.login(uri.user, uri.password)
ftp.putbinaryfile('./output/index.html')
ftp.close
```

As you can see, it's a pretty straightforward code. I have tried entering the host and port by hand with no change in outcome. (Although I swear I got it to work, but I haven't since been able to replicate the result.) It works locally on my Cloud9 IDE, but not on Heroku.

**Problem**

After the ftp.connect command is entered, I get an error. Here is the full IRB run through recreating the error with the host and port hardcoded (and confirmed to work through the Cloud9 IDE):

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'uri'
=> true    
irb(main):002:0> require 'net/ftp'
=> true    
irb(main):003:0> ftp = Net::FTP.new
=> #<Net::FTP:0x007f65e242c850 @mon_owner=nil, @mon_count=0, @mon_mutex=#<Thread::Mutex:0x007f65e242c7b0>, @binary=true, @passive=true, @debug_mode=false, @resume=false, @sock=#<Net::FTP::NullSocket:0x007f65e242c788>, @logged_in=false, @open_timeout=nil, @read_timeout=60>    
irb(main):004:0> ftp.debug_mode = true
=> true
irb(main):005:0> ftp.passive = true
=> true    
irb(main):006:0> ftp.connect("ftp.rakuten.ne.jp", "16910")
connect: ftp.rakuten.ne.jp, 16910
EOFError: end of file reached    
        from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/ftp.rb:1310:in `readline'    
        from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/ftp.rb:305:in `getline'    
        from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/ftp.rb:317:in `getmultiline'    
        from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/ftp.rb:334:in `getresp'
        from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/ftp.rb:354:in `voidresp'    
        from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/ftp.rb:264:in `block in connect'    
        from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'    
        from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/ftp.rb:262:in `connect'    
        from (irb):6    
        from /app/bin/irb:15:in `<main>'
```

**Addendum**

Any help you can give me would be greatly appreciated. I'm relatively new to Ruby and extremely new to Heroku, but I really want to get this working.

If it is impossible on Heroku, can anyone recommend another option to deploy the script as intended?

Added: Okay, so the code does work as intended on Heroku sometimes. I just tried it this morning through IRB and the connection held. A scheduled run then also worked, but after that I tried to fix a separate issue with using the retrieved mail attachment data at the top of the code and the FTP connection started failing again with the same error. It still works locally, however.

Comment: I can't connect to the server `ftp.rakuten.ne.jp` on either the normal port or `16910` either with a plain FTP client. I would say the server is either misconfigured, or it's not allowing connections from unknown IP addresses. In any case, your Ruby code looks fine.

Comment: That is strange. I have never had a problem connecting from my various computers nor from Cloud9. Could it be a geographical region block perhaps? 

I am based in Japan, Cloud9 seems to have servers somewhere in Asia... Maybe Rakuten's ftp server is blocking connections from outside Japan?

Comment: That's possible. I just tried it again (from The Netherlands) and I can connect but the TCP connection is immediately closed ... Definitely seems to be *something* on the server-side. What exactly? I can only guess... Usually firewalls outright block connections instead of opening it and then immediately closing it, though...

Comment: Thank you for trying. I'm trying to use a Japanese PaaS similar to Heroku. I'll check back in when I get everything running!